# How to Join two MongoDB Collections with the Unity JDBC driver?

Tags: sql, mongodb, jdbc

From the Unity JDBC [download page](http://www.unityjdbc.com/download.php?type=mongodb):

> If the SQL query requires joins or functions not supported by MongoDB, then the query is promoted to UnityJDBC (trial version). The UnityJDBC trial version has no expiration date and is fully functioning except that it is limited to returning up to 100 results.

However, when I try to join two tables using any syntax like

```
SELECT * from a, b WHERE a.id = b.id
SELECT * from a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
SELECT * from a INNER JOIN b USING (id)
```

Results in the following:

```
Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR: No schema defined.  The default schema location is _schema in the current database.  You need write permission to create this collection.  Otherwise, use the schema parameter to set a file location (e.g. schema=mongo.xml) to store the schema.  See connection parameters at http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/ for more details.
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR: No schema defined.  The default schema location is _schema in the current database.  You need write permission to create this collection.  Otherwise, use the schema parameter to set a file location (e.g. schema=mongo.xml) to store the schema.  See connection parameters at http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/ for more details.
    at mongodb.conn.ServerConnection.processMongoWithUnity(Unknown Source)
    at mongodb.conn.ServerConnection.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at mongodb.jdbc.MongoStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at mongodb.ExampleMongoJDBC.doQuery(ExampleMongoJDBC.java:222)
    at mongodb.ExampleMongoJDBC.main(ExampleMongoJDBC.java:66)
```

Ok, so I took a look in the readme and found it mentioning the code/test/dspec/ folder with some files related to schemas. I opened a few up, they are highly detailed xml files of all the collections mapping them to relational data types.

Do I have to write one of these out, or is there a way to auto generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a (fast) response from the Unity team.

> The MongoDB JDBC driver has two modes.  For single collection queries, it does not build a schema.  For queries involving joins or expressions it builds a schema and by default stores it in the _schema collection in the current Mongo database.  If you do not have permission to write to the database, an error is thrown.
>
> As mentioned in the error, you can set the schema parameter to be a local file name (such as mongo.xml) and it will store it on your computer rather than in the Mongo database.  You could also use an account that has write permissions.
>
> To make this work, add schema=mongo.xml to your connection URL like this:

```
jdbc:mongo://localhost/dbname?schema=mongo.xml?rebuildschema=true
```

After this is done the first time, you can remove the rebuildschema=true or it will rebuild it every time.

The only thing I'm confused about is that I'm using a database which doesn't require authentication. I even made a user with write permissions, connected to him, and still received the above error.

--EDIT

I realized that you could also just do `jdbc:mongo://localhost/dbname?rebuildschema=true`. If the schema hasn't been created, then the previous error will be thrown.